# Insert Image From Google Form to Google Slides

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-slides

I am trying to make a report that's generated from google form answers. I found some way to populate the text but the problem is i need to add the images from google form answers on my report in google slides. I am not a developer so can anyone help me with it? Here's the code that i've tried:

```js
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  //open the template presentation by ID
  var templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById('1ytA5aje8eTW4tQOf9U_DCKlpLrnLYZna3KIvjz9rx1Q');
  //create a copy of the template
  var newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy();
  
  //open the presentation for editing
  var openSlide = SlidesApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());

  //get the responses triggered by On Form Submit
  var items = e.response.getItemResponses();
  //var amountof_item = items[4].getResponse();

  //find the text in the presentation and replace it with the Form response
  //items[0].getResponse() is the first response in the Form
  openSlide.replaceAllText('{PM In Charge :}', items[0].getResponse());
  openSlide.replaceAllText('{Homeowner Name :}', items[1].getResponse());
  openSlide.replaceAllText('{Location :}', items[2].getResponse());
  openSlide.replaceAllText('{Week :}', items[3].getResponse());
  openSlide.replaceAllText('{Report Date :}', items[4].getResponse());
  openSlide.replaceAllText('{Start Date :}', items[6].getResponse());
  openSlide.replaceAllText('{End Date :}', items[7].getResponse());
  openSlide.replaceAllText('{Rooms :}', items[8].getResponse());
  openSlide.replaceAllText('{Work Item :}', items[9].getResponse());
  openSlide.replaceAllText('{Work Item Progress :}', items[10].getResponse());
  openSlide.replaceAllText('{Work Item File/Image :}', items[11].getResponse());

  //Save and Close the open document
  openSlide.saveAndClose();
  DriveApp.getFileById(newTempFile.getId()).setName(items[1].getResponse() + "-" + items[3].getResponse() + "-Progress");
 }
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `but the problem is i need to add the images from google form answers on my report in google slides.` and your showing script and your current issue. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike  thank you for replying. My google form allows the respondents to upload images, i want those images to be displayed on my google slides template automatically every time they submit the response. I've tried my code above but it only returns the text and not the image. I hope i've made my self clear ^^

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, in your script, the image is only `items[11]`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Correct @Tanaike it is items[11] that contains image

Comment: Thank you for replying. As one more question, in your Google Slide, it is only one page in the Slides?

Comment: It has multiple slides in my Google Slide @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- In your Google Form and your script, only `items[11].getResponse()` is the uploaded image.
- Your Google Slides has multiple slides.

When `replaceAllText` is used, the text is replaced. In this case, the text cannot be replaced with the image. And, I think that the value of `items[11].getResponse()` is the file ID. This is the reason for your issue. In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
openSlide.replaceAllText('{Work Item File/Image :}', items[11].getResponse());
```

#### To:

```
var image = items[11].getResponse();
openSlide.getSlides().forEach(s => {
  s.getShapes().forEach(e => {
    if (e.getText().asString().trim() == '{Work Item File/Image :}') {
      e.replaceWithImage(DriveApp.getFileById(Array.isArray(image) ? image[0] : image).getBlob());
    }
  })
});
```

- When this script is run, the file ID of the image file is retrieved from `items[11].getResponse()`, and retrieve the blob from the file, and then, the image blob is replaced with the text of `{Work Item File/Image :}` of each page.

#### References:

- [getSlides()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#getslides)
- [replaceWithImage(blobSource)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#replaceWithImage(BlobSource))

Comment: Thank you so much @Tanaike. I've tried this and it works perfectly in my case. Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: @fj_gie Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand your question with your cooperation. Through this, I could think of a solution. Thank you, too.